# Adding label inside multiseries doughnut chart through chart.js

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I have implemented multi-series doughnut chart using chart.js in react application. I want to show label of each section inside chart as a text in both inner and outer chart. To implement this, I tried chart-js-plugin-labels. But it is working only for the outer chart labels. Does anyone have any solution for that?

Here is one demo application I found similar to my implementation, for the reference.
[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/moe2ggrd/1/)

A part of applying inside text labels for chart is mentioned below:

```
var refChart = document.getElementById("dchart");
var chartConfig = new Chart(refChart, {
            type: 'doughnut',
            data: {
                datasets: [
                   {
                    data: [4, 3, 3, 2],
                    label: 'data1',
                    labels: ['A','C','B','C']
                   }, 
                   {
                    data: [5, 3, 2],
                    label: 'data2',
                    labels: ['X','Y','Z'],
                   }]
                 },

             options:{
                  responsive: true,
                  maintainAspectRatio:false,
                  legend: {
                    display: true,
                    position: 'bottom',
                         }
                  plugins:{
                    labels:{
                        render:"label",
                        arc:true,
                           }
                         }
                     }
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datalabels plugin of chart.js has what you are looking for from what I understand of your explanation:

Example: https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/samples/charts/doughnut.html

Github: https://github.com/chartjs/chartjs-plugin-datalabels